# Hacer un search que encuentre una palabra si no esta precedida por otra palabra en especifico

Tags: python, regex

Necesito poder saber si en un string se encuentra la palabra "mañana" PERO no esta precedida por la palabra "la"

Ejemplos:
Que devuelva **True** en:

> "nos vemos mañana"
>
> "nos vemos mañana a la mañana"

Que devuelva **False** en:

> "nos vemos a la mañana"

Voy a poner un ejemplo ultra simple de lo que quiero.

```py
frase = input()

#if esta la palabra "mañana" en la frase pero no esta precedida por la palabra "la":
    print('Encontre al menos un caso')
else:
    print('No encontre nada')
```

Uso Python 3.

Comment: Debes compartir el código que tu has generado e indicar cual es el comportamiento de tu programa y cual es el error especifico que estas teniendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\bla\b)(?<!\W)\W*\bmañana\b
```

- **`?<!`** -> Mirada hacia atrás negativa, no coincide con la expresión siguiente:

  - **`\b`** -> inicio de una palabra
  - **`la`** -> literar "la"
  - **`\b`** -> final de una palabra
- **`? <!`** -> Mirada hacia atrás negativa, no coincide con la expresión siguiente

  - **`\W`** -> coincide con cualquier carácter que no conforme una palabra.
- **`W`** -> coincide con cualquier carácter que no conforme una palabra.
- **`*`** -> coincide entre cero e ilimitadas veces, tantas veces como sea posible (codicioso).
- **`\b`** -> inicio de una palabra
- **`mañana`** -> literar "mañana"
- **`\b`** -> final de una palabra

---

```
import re


frases = ("la mañana es buena",
          "en la mañana lo hago",
          "mañana la veo",
          "siendo mañana la puedo ver",
          "en la mañana de mañana",
          "en una mala mañana", 
          "por mañanas", 
          "Es un cantamañanas")

for frase in frases:
    print(f'{"-" * 74}\nFRASE: "{frase}"')
    if re.search(r"(?<!\bla\b)(?<!\W)\W*\bmañana\b", frase):
        print('RESULTADO: Encontre al menos un caso')
    else:
        print('RESULTADO: No encontre nada')
    print("-" * 74)
```

> ```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FRASE: "la mañana es buena"
> RESULTADO: No encontre nada
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FRASE: "en la mañana lo hago"
> RESULTADO: No encontre nada
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FRASE: "mañana la veo"
> RESULTADO: Encontre al menos un caso
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FRASE: "siendo mañana la puedo ver"
> RESULTADO: Encontre al menos un caso
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FRASE: "en la mañana de mañana"
> RESULTADO: Encontre al menos un caso
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FRASE: "en una mala mañana"
> RESULTADO: Encontre al menos un caso
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FRASE: "por mañanas"
> RESULTADO: No encontre nada
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> FRASE: "Es un cantamañanas"
> RESULTADO: No encontre nada
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Si te interesa una solución que no dependa (tanto) de expresiones regulares, podrías utilizar algo así:

```
import re

def tiene_mañana(str):
    return re.search(r"\bmañana\b", str, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

def tiene_la_mañana(str):
    return re.search(r"\bla\s+mañana\b", str, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

def evalua_frase(str):
    if tiene_mañana(str) and not tiene_la_mañana(str):
        print(str + " ==> Sí")
    else:
        print(str + " ==> No")

evalua_frase('Me levanto por la mañana')
evalua_frase('Lo haré mañana')
evalua_frase('la palabra mañanas es un plural')
evalua_frase('la palabra mañana es singular')
```

Tanto para el método `tiene_mañana` como `tiene_la_mañana` debes saber que es importante utilizar el `limite de palabra` o `\b`.

Esto avisa al motor de expresiones regulares que la palabra debe terminar ahí. Así evitamos encontrar `la` dentro de `Hola`, por ejemplo.

Por otro lado, `\s+` te permite separar `la` y `mañana` por uno o más 'espacios' (entendiendo por espacios: espacios, saltos de línea, tabuladores, ...)

Answer (score 1):

estuve desarrollando varias pruebas basadas en el ejemplo de tu pregunta y implementando el uso de Rejex llegando a la siguiente conclusión mostrándote ahora el ejemplo mas simple/básico .

```
import re

frases =["nos vemos mañana","nos vemos mañana a la mañana","nos vemos a la mañana"]

for a in range(0,3):
    if(re.search("mañana a la",frases[a])is not None):
        print("true")
    elif(re.search("la mañana",frases[a])is not None):
        print("false")
    elif(re.search("mañana",frases[a])is not None):
        print("true")
    else:
        print("No se encontraron Coincidencias")
```

Es importante que este se encuentre en la ultima anidación porque sino siempre daría true ya que todas contienen la palabra "mañana"(empieza por la comprobación de las cadenas mas largas) :

```
 elif(re.search("mañana",frases[a])is not None):
            print("true")
```

Te reitero que este código es la forma mas simple de hacer este ejercicio con Regex y es funcional.Aun así te invito a refinar el código compartiendo te:

1.-[Documentacion oficial de regex para python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

2.-[online regex para correr tus pruebas fácilmente] (https://regex101.com)

3.-[recomiendo el uso de def ya que es mas eficiente que anidar tantos if](https://medium.com/@BryanMiranda/simular-un-switch-en-python3-35415520bf1f)

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero ten en cuenta que para evaluar la frase estás comparando contra tres frases 'fijas': "mañana a la", "a la mañana" y "mañana". Cualquier otra variación hará que no funcione el programa: Por ejemplo: "me gusta la mañana"

Comment: se arreglara con tan solo quitar la letra "a" contenida en el if(ya actualice el código),sin embargo hay que poner n cantidad de valoraciones .

Comment: Así arreglas uno de los problemas, pero hay alguno más. Creo que la primera condición no aporta nada ya que está contemplada en la tercera. Y tener esa condición inicial puede ser fuente de problemas. Por ejemplo, como con la frase "la mañana a la". Por otro lado, necesitarías algo para para vigilar los `limite de palabras` Por ejemplo con la frase "Hola mañana"

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurrió una solución. No se si es la más eficiente pero funciona. Básicamente es sacar del string los "falsos positivos" (la mañana) y volver a revisar el string en busca de la palabra. Me quedó así:

```py
frase = input()

if 'mañana' in re.sub(r'\bla\s*mañana\b','', frase):
    print('Encontre al menos un caso')
else:
    print('No encontre nada')
```

Comment: Es interesante, sin embaro te faltó jugar un poco con los límites de palabra para no encontrar cosas como: 'Hola mañana' o 'mañanas'

Comment: @Julio Muy cierto, creo que agregando '\b' al principio y al final (como indicaste en tu solucion) lo arreglo. Gracias!

Comment: Mejor! pero cuando busques mañana también deberías tener en cuenta los límites de la palabra. Si no, podrías dar como bueno: 'mañanas' o 'cantamañanas'